# get html code into a php variable

Tags: php

I'm don't use PHP that much and right now I'm stuck at a problem.
I need to save the site of a webbrowser as a pdf. I'm using right now mPDF (which was suggested in a wiki of stackoverflow) and it seems to work pretty well (I just have simply write a short html code into a php variable and then created the pdf).

But now I must get the html code of the actual site in the browser and save it then into a php variable. How can I do that?

Comment: Okay I need to add more details. The site is generated by a php code. So if I would give that code to the printer, then it will be a mess. Furthermore, it must be user friendly, meaning that a user just can press a save button and then the pdf will be generated. (The user sees a confirm html page and he wants to save that confirm page as a pdf)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can probably fetch the remote content via PHPs [`file_get_contents()`-function](http://php.net/file_get_contents):

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://example.org');
```

If this does not work, make sure that you have [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) enabled in your php.ini.

Comment: the problem is that the during the process the link does not change. for example your order contains 2 pages. first page = choose product, second page = confirmation. now i just want to save the confirmation page as a pdf. when i use your solution, then i have a pdf file containing the first page, which is also empty (you dont your selection), because with file_get_contents('') it loads the page from new on...

Comment: Okay, i get the problem. The problem is, that the server cannot (or should not) use the clients session to get the same view of the website. I think you might need the [`ob_*`-functions](http://php.net/ob_) to capture the output of the page you want to put into your PDF. Do it like this: If the user invokes the page with a print-parameter (provided by your print-link), you print your page as usual. But you do it like Sarfraz suggested. `ob_start()` before your page is printed, `ob_get_contents()` afterwards to recieve the output. `ob_end_clean()` prevents PHP from sending the output.

Comment: What do you mean with "print your page as usual?". The page is written php, meaning that it contains a mix of html and php code. right now the print button just calls another .php file (action='printpdf.php') and that file has a small code which print the content of my provided php variable.

Comment: Simply do not link to a new page. Instead, link to the current page and provide a parameter like `?print=true` to indicate wether the page should be output as PDF. Invoke the `ob_*`-functions if that parameter is set: `ob_start()` at the top (above everything that leads to output), `ob_get_contents()` and `ob_end_clean()` at the very bottom.

Answer (score 8):

If I understand you correctly, you can store page contents into php variable like this:

```
ob_start();

// your html code goes here

$contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

// see the contents now
echo $contents;
```

Comment: `$contents = ob_get_clean();` alone will do the job as ob_get_clean() both returns the value of buffer and cleans it.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably over-kill, but you can try using [SimpleHTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) which can load a remote website and extract out its HTML.